# How to manually calculate the weight of configurable product

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, configurable-product

i have the following problem:
when I try to edit an order in Magento, on the initial loading of the edit page, 
`Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request::getPackageWeight()` returns zero.This behaviour occurs only with configurable products.

My question is how can i calculate manually the total weight of the package.
I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 CE.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight of quote items is calculated by the shipping total model `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping` in the `collect()` method.

After the item weight is collected, the total model then calls `$address->collectShippingRates();` to trigger the shipping rate calculation.

I suggest you look at the loop in the total model mentioned above, where it iterates over each item, to see why a configurable doesn't get a weight value assigned.

The only thing I can think of without further access is that maybe you have a sales rule in place that sets `free_shipping` on the quote item.

Before you wonder, the `weight_type` attribute is only used for `bundled` products to indicate if the total weight should be fixed or calculated dynamically from the associated products.